# PID Control for multiple control dependent variables

Tags: pid

I am working to control the force output of a 3PRS parallel robot. (Linear force along z, moment about x and y). The primary goal is to keep the force output in the linear z direction constant (30N) and the moment about x and y axis to zero. The 3PRS robot is equipped with a three displacement sensor on each prismatic joint and a 6 DoF F/T sensor on the Cartesian space. I use the displacement sensor value to calculate the forward kinematics and Jacobian and I use the force sensor feedback (Fx, Nx, Ny) as a control feedback for my PID.

MY trial: I take the feedback (Fx, Nx, Ny) and compare it with my desired value (30, 0, 0) and take the error, derror and ierror and multiplied it by kp, kd and ki and formulate a control signal (F_signal = Fd+(kp*error+kd*derror+ki*ierror) in the Cartesian space. After that I use the Jacobian to calculate joint space signal (F_Jointspace = J*Fd_signal). Once I get the joint space signal I calculate the necessary pressure value to feed my cylinders since the actuation system is pneumatic.

But I can achieve a best for the torques, the gains barely affects the result. Any strategy could be helpful. Thank you